# Multiple Bootstrap Tables in one page - wenzhixin

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to have two Bootstrap Tables  in the same page but, it just loads the one that is in the second script. Could anyone help me to figure out what is not allowing me to do this?

I thought it was an id conflict but I'm not sure, since having two ids called the same cause troubles, but I would like to know what is going on here.

I'm using same script like [this](http://issues.wenzhixin.net.cn/bootstrap-table/), but I separated my scripts from my HTML.

If I load one script works perfectly.

**Table for Roles**

```
<table id="tableRoles"
   data-toolbar="#toolbarRoles"
   data-search="true"
   data-show-refresh="true"
   data-show-toggle="true"
   data-show-columns="true"
   data-show-export="true"
   data-detail-view="false"
   data-minimum-count-columns="2"
   data-show-pagination-switch="true"
   data-pagination="true"
   data-id-field="RoleID"
   data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
   data-show-footer="false"
   data-side-pagination="server"
   data-url="modules/registrarRoles/getRoles.php"
   data-sort-name="RoleID"
   data-sort-order="asc"
   data-row-style="rowStyleRoles">
</table>
```

**Table for Users**

```
<table id="tableUsers"
 data-toolbar="#toolbar"
 data-search="true"
 data-show-refresh="true"
 data-show-toggle="true"
 data-show-columns="true"
 data-show-export="true"
 data-detail-view="false"
 data-detail-formatter="detailFormatter"
 data-minimum-count-columns="2"
 data-show-pagination-switch="true"
 data-pagination="true"
 data-id-field="UserID"
 data-page-list="[10, 25, 50, 100, ALL]"
 data-show-footer="false"
 data-side-pagination="server"
 data-url="modules/registrarUsuarios/getUsuarios.php"
 data-response-handler="responseHandler"
 data-sort-name="UserID"
 data-sort-order="asc"
 data-row-style="rowStyle">
</table>
```

**Script for one of them** (They are in different js files)

```
var $tableRoles = $('#tableRoles'),
    data, 
    selections = [];
    console.log('working');
function initTable() {
    $tableRoles.bootstrapTable({
        height: getHeight(),
        columns: [
            [
                {
                    title: 'Roles',
                    colspan: 8,
                    align: 'center'
                }
            ],
            [
                {
                    field: 'RoleID',
                    title: 'ID',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    sortable: true,
                    searchable: true,
                    footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
                }, {
                    field: 'RoleName',
                    title: 'Nombre de Rol',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    field: 'Description',
                    title: 'Descripcion',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center',
                    footerFormatter: totalNameFormatter
                }, {
                    field: 'RoleGroupID',
                    title: 'Grupo',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    field: 'Status',
                    title: 'Status',
                    align: 'center',
                    valign: 'middle',
                    sortable: true,
                    searchable: true,
                    footerFormatter: totalTextFormatter
                },{
                    field: 'activeFromDate',
                    title: 'Activo Desde',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center'
                }, {
                    field: 'activeUntilDate',
                    title: 'Activo Hasta',
                    sortable: true,
                    align: 'center'
                },  {
                    field: 'operate',
                    title: 'Acciones',
                    align: 'center',
                    events: operateEventsRoles,
                    formatter: operateFormatterRoles
                }
            ]
        ]
    });
```

[Here are the tables in Developer tools](https://i.stack.imgur.com/agkCA.png)

Comment: Exists the possibilit of twice table staying render in the same position? You can see both ate inspect element of browser?

Comment: No, they are in different positions, I'll update  a pic